# how to use value.labels in sjt.frq command inside sjPlot library?

Tags: r, sjplot

Hi to everyone my question is about the use of this parameter.

A quick example:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
```

for this example 1 = yes and 2 = No, then:

```
sjt.frq(x,
        value.labels = c("yes","no"))
```

But the result is not showing me the labels.

I try this other method:

```
lab <- c("Si" = 1, 
         "No" = 2)


sjt.frq(x,
        value.labels = lab)
```

with no success

I know I can use this workaround:

```
library(sjmisc)
sjt.frq(add_labels(x,value = lab))
```

But I want to figure out how to use sjt.frq with value.labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the current version - labelling the output only works for labelled data, argument `value.label` is not handled properly. You can either wait for a package-update of sjPlot :-) or label your vector:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
x <- set_labels(x, labels = c("si", "non"))
sjt.frq(x)
```

`sjt.frq(x, value.labels = c("yes","no"))` would be correct if the bug is fixed. I committed a fix to GitHub (https://github.com/sjPlot), so you could install the current build to make `sjt.frq()` work correct.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how this work? Now i know is a bug. I looked in github, and notice the fix. I will try github. Thanks you very much! Gracias!